# Is it possible to define a User-Defined Table Type with an `Always Encrypted` column in it?

Tags: sql-server, always-encrypted, user-defined-data-types

I have a SP that accepts a `user-defined table type` table and does inserts and updates to a database table.

Example:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[MySP1] (@InsertData dbo.MyDataType READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (A, B, C)
    SELECT  ia.A, ia.B, ia.C
    FROM    @InsertData AS ia
END
```

Recently, I have decided to encrypt one column of that database table (`dbo.MyTable`) using Always Encrypted.

Now, in order to keep the SP operational, I (guess I) will have to update the user table type (`dbo.MyDataType`) to contain an `Always Encrypted` column.

But this doesn't seem possible to me, neither from the SSMS GUI, nor via T-SQL.

E.g., this fails:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyDataType] AS TABLE(
    [A] [INT] NULL,
    [B] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [C] [VARCHAR](MAX) COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK_Auto1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = RANDOMIZED, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL
)
```

Is this possible? If not, are they any alternatives? Passing the the table values as scalar values to the SP is not very possible, since I will have to call that SP as many times as the number of the rows in the original user defined table.

Comment: This is explicitly [documented as unsupported](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine#limitations). If your stored procedure does nothing very interesting, an alternative would be to eliminate it in favor of directly inserting into the table from the client (round-trip overhead can be minimized by doing things in a transaction). Alternatively, handle encryption client-side entirely so the limitations of Always Encrypted don't apply (though you lose the transparency this way, of course).

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert. My SP also does some security checks, so the 1st option will probably not be ideal. Any hints that help on figuring out the C# code used to encrypt the data programmatically would be welcome.

Comment: The basic approach would be the same as the one AE is using: generate a strong, long key used to asymmetrically encrypt a key which is in turn used in symmetric encryption like AES for the actual data (since using asymmetric encryption for everything would be too slow). The process AE uses is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-cryptography); you would not necessarily have to follow the same steps, but something similar.

Comment: I see that, if I try to update the encrypted column with a `VARBINARY(MAX)` value inside the SP, it fails with this error while updating the SP: `Operand type clash: varbinary(max) is incompatible with varchar(max) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', ...`. Is there a way to cast this to an encrypted `VARCHAR(MAX)`?

Comment: Nope. That, too, is mentioned as unsupported on the same page I linked earlier. If you were to move encryption to the client side, then the field would have to change to an (unencrypted!) `VARBINARY(MAX)`, and you would only get it as a string after decryption. The only loophole there is when [bulk loading encrypted data](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/migrate-sensitive-data-protected-by-always-encrypted), but this is intended for migration scenarios.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was all SO helpful! It appears I have problems locating the information I need in the documentation :( . You could post an answer with all this info so that I can accept it, if you want. Or I could add an answer myself, if you don't want to spend extra time.

Comment: I dont really get what microsoft was thinking with AE. It has so many limitations, especially the INSERT/UPDATE ones that it becomes unuseful in my humble opinion.